# Is it possible to set the size attribute of a select element using JavaScript in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a page with following HTML

```
<select id="person" size="5" onchange="document.getElementById('person').size = 1;">
    <option value="Homer">Homer</option>
    <option value="Marge">Marge</option>
    <option value="Bart">Bart</option>
    <option value="Lisa">Lisa</option>
    <option value="Maggie">Maggie</option>
</select>
```

When you select an item in the list, the list's size is set to 1 (so it renders as a combo box rather than a list box).

When using Internet Explorer 11, the browser crashes. When testing with other browsers there is no problem. I have tried the following browsers:

- Firefox 25.0.1
- Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m
- Internet Explorer 10

There is a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/pC9zL/11/ containing the above HTML.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and if so are they aware of any possible solutions?

Comment: Crash confirmed, IE 11.

Comment: As a first workaround I’d try to clone the select element, set its size before the clone is appended to the DOM, and then replace the original select element with the clone.

Comment: Looks like a bug in IE11. Also setting `size` attribute to `1` or even removing it crashes IE11. I tried to found a report about the issue from Microsoft Connect, and found [your report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811300/setting-the-size-attribute-of-a-select-element-to-1-causes-ie11-to-crash) : ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @CBroe suggests, you can create a new element and replace the current one by it. Using [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) to create a “deep” copy, you can do that this way:

```
<select id="person" size="5" onchange="toDropdown(this)">
    <option value="Homer">Homer</option>
    <option value="Marge">Marge</option>
    <option value="Bart">Bart</option>
    <option value="Lisa">Lisa</option>
    <option value="Maggie">Maggie</option>
</select>
<script>
function toDropdown(select) {
  var dropdown = select.cloneNode(true);
  dropdown.selectedIndex = select.selectedIndex;
  dropdown.size = 1;
  select.parentNode.replaceChild(dropdown, select);
}
</script>
```

This does not crash IE 11. It seems to have an issue with the change of a *rendered* `select` in a manner that requires a completely change of the rendering principle (from listbox to dropdown). But it can handle such a change when you replace the rendered element by another one.

Comment: This solution does work and we have successfully integrated it into our application, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and occurs with onChange event. Using onClick event solved the crash problem

```html
<select id="person" size="5" onclick="document.getElementById('person').size = 1;">
    <option value="Homer">Homer</option>
    <option value="Marge">Marge</option>
    <option value="Bart">Bart</option>
    <option value="Lisa">Lisa</option>
    <option value="Maggie">Maggie</option>
</select>
```

More info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4c5643f9-2d54-4a64-9f24-47a4b73fd618/select-box-size-change-crashes-ie11